# MS SQL: How to create user that has only permission for defined views?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a User that only has permission for defined views.

This is how it should work then:
- DB01 => Permission denied 
- vView01 => success

At the moment each User has Permission to Views and Datebase or none...

Any Ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Bernhard

Comment: this seems better suited to DBA than SO, and it has probably already been answered there, e.g. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17177/how-to-add-a-user-with-access-to-a-single-view

Answer (score 1):

Grant user permissions only on views and [ownership chaining](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676(v=sql.105).aspx) will allow access to the underlying tables even without permissions on those objects as long as all objects involved have the same owner.

Unfortunately, the is no `GRANT` syntax to grant permissions on all current and future views such that the user has permissions current and new views. However, this functionality could be accomplished by creating views in a different schema and granting permissions at the schema level:

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::ViewSchema TO <some-user-or-role>;
```

Otherwise, you'll need to grant permissions on existing views and on each new one after creation. Below is an example script to make quick work for this task.

```
DECLARE @GrantScript nvarchar(MAX);

SET @GrantScript = (
    SELECT N'GRANT SELECT ON ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id))  + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + N' TO <some-user-or-role>;'
    FROM sys.views
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)');

EXEC sp_executesql @GrantScript;
```